# How to download a new version of Flash Player executable for opening SWF files and Flash IDE

Tags: flash, fdt, flash-ide

I would like to update the swf player that I specify into FDT and what Flash IDE uses to play files, namely from Flash 10 to Flash 11 for Stage3d preview. How does one do this?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\Players or al;ong those lines for your os/flash ide version

Answer (score 1):

One goes to the [Adobe Flash Player Support Center](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html), and download there latest versions of the debug flash players, according to the system, and browser one needs.

Comment: http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer11.html - Yes I am aware. Those installers install into the specified browser, not into the flash player in Flash IDE or provide a FlashPlayer.exe

Comment: try to install all 4 versions for your OS, that are listed there, I almost sure this will update everything you need, and one of them is a standalone player.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial I wrote here:

http://fdt.powerflasher.com/blog/2011/08/setting-up-away-3d-4-0-loading-a-3d-model/

For the newer '3D' stuff you'll need to test it in a browser environment, see the 'Analyzing The Setup'.

In general, to change which stand alone player you're using - you need to change this in the *Preferences > FDT > Tools > Flash* section.

See more here:
http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Launch_Configuration_Tutorial